# How can I fix this error?: ImportError: cannot import name 'titlescreen'

Tags: python

So, I've been trying to make a title screen for my game. In this title screen, you can choose to start playing or you can choose to read the game rules. The rules and the title are both definitions in different .py files.

I have tried importing the definitions to the tittle screen and to the instructions. But as soon as I import the title to the instruction file, It will tell me that it isn't possible to import it.

```
#tittlescreen.py file

import sys,time,random
import fileinput, time
from time import sleep
from rules import instructions
from begin import start
import os

answer = None

while answer not in ("1" , "2"):

    answer = input(" Type '1' or '2': ")

    if answer == "1":
      os.system('clear')
      start()
    elif answer == "2":
      os.system('clear')
      instructions()          #It's here that it begins to have a problem
```

```
#rules.py File

import sys,time,random
import fileinput, time
from time import sleep
from titlescreen import titlescreen
from begin import start
import os

proceed = "1"

  while proceed not in ("0"):
    pross = input("Press '0' to begin playing.")
    if pross == "0":
      os.system('clear')
      titlescreen()          #And here
```

The error that shows up is this one:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 4, in <module>
    from titlescreen import titlescreen
  File "/home/runner/titlescreen.py", line 4, in <module>
    from instructions import instruções
  File "/home/runner/instructions.py", line 4, in <module>
    from titlescreen import titlescreen
ImportError: cannot import name 'titlescreen'
```

I don't know why it won't let me import the "titlescreen" definition to the "instructions" definition.

I really do hope that I can make a working title screen and instructions that can access eachother, just like in a normal game.

Comment: There's a comment at the beginning of the first snippet of code in your question that says `#tittlescreen.py file`. Is that the filename or is it a typo?

Answer (score 1):

I am assuming that you want to run the "titlescreen.py" file when you call titlescreen() in the "rules.py" file. Right? Unfortunately, that's not exactly how "from titlescreen import titlescreen" works.

Take this similar example. The way the following code works...

```
from X import Y
```

Is that Python looks in the file named X.py for a function definition named Y. Since there are no functions in titlescreen.py, it can't find anything!

If you want to import a function named "titlescreen" in the file titlescreen.py, and it should look something like this...

```
def titlescreen():
    answer = None

    while answer not in ("1" , "2"):

        answer = input(" Type '1' or '2': ")

        if answer == "1":
            os.system('clear')
            start()
        elif answer == "2":
            os.system('clear')
            instructions()
```

Hopefully that does the trick.